# Handling of obsolete but non-deleteable columns

Tags: database, oracle

We have some columns in our database which are now obsolete. The columns are not used for anything currently, but we can't just drop the column as we might need the data, to find out why our application handled the way it did, sometime in the past.

We see that with Oracle 12c we got the option of making the column "invisible". This seems to fit our use-case: We wouldn't have to drop the column, but the column wouldn't be nuisance in day-to-day work. Not taking up visual space when watching the table and not being included when querying entire rows from the table.

As we have no experience with "invisible" we'd like to know if there are some negatives we're not seeing or if there are other "best-practices" we should consider instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting obsolete columns to `invisible` is a good way to deprecate them.

Main thing you'll want to do is remove `not null`constraints before making them invisible. Or you can get some unexpected errors:

```
create table t (
  c1 int, 
  c2 int
    invisible
    not null
);

desc t

Name   Null?   Type         
C1               NUMBER(38)   

insert into t values ( 1 );

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("CHRIS"."T"."C2")
```

Worst case, you do find a problem and make it visible again. Though this will [change the column order for `select *`](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-oracle-database-12c-part-5).